# Unavailable Selenium node for Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, grid, webdriver

This problem is making me crazy. I'll try to explain it.

I have a Selenium grid environment with two machines (HUB & NODE). I use .bat files to start the hub and the nodes, something like the code below: 
*HUB:*

Here I start the hub:

```
start java -jar C:\workspace\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar  -role hub -port 4444
```

Here I start a .bat on the node machine that will start the node.

```
psexec.exe \\XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -s -e -u USER -p PASSWORD -i 2 C:\Selenium\StartNode.bat
```

*NODE:*

To register the node:

```
java -jar C:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node  -hub http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:4444/grid/register
```

I have this from the beginning (more or less 6 moths) and was fine and simple, but now I see very weird (for me) things but only in Internet Explorer. Basically, the node starts, IE opens to correct page but nothing happens. I just have  "object not found errors..." Firefox and Chrome are just fine.
But, if I start the node directly on it (NODE machine, so not from HUB via psexec), it works fine for IE as well?

Do you guys have any logical explanation? I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to provide IEDriver exe when starting the node like below.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.100:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=10.0,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.internetexplorer.driver=c:\Selenium\InternetExplorerDriver.exe
```

Comment: i just use a node for 3 browsers so don't pass that parameter, but I checked, and it doesn't work

Comment: well, if I look at the browser it just starts to the correct www but after that ( there is a login) , i receiver standard warning like "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression './/*[@href='/application?appid=51' and @class='inner .popoverOption']' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement".But, i just saw the log has a weird message for internet explorer.

Comment: org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy - Trying to create a new session on node host :http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5555
org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSlot - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=VISTA, browserName=internet explorer, maxInstances=1}
rg.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy - Failed to check status of node: Connect to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5555 [/192.168.10.117] failed: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Ok. That doesn't mean the node is available. Title of your question is misleading. Xpath on IE are brittle because IE doesn't have native xpath engine, selenium injects it. Did you try css like a.popoverOption

Answer (score 0):

Try to create node using such command:
`java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe -jar C:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig C:\selenium\nodeIE1.json`

I used `node` instead `webdriver` (the last one is used for backward compatibility) and latest version of [IEDriverServer](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/)

It works great for me. And you may try nssm to run your hub and node as win services instead using .bat files.

Comment: the fact is that i didn't change anything, just started to "not working"

Comment: Did it work with previous version of selenium-serever, selenium-java? E.g. I've faced today with the issue that chromedriver does not work with selenium-java 2.45. I have rolled back to 44 and it started to work again.

Comment: it worked fine with 2.44 , and with 2.45 for a few days ! so weird :-(. tried to revert and the same stuff , no way. The point is that if start hub on hub and node on node ( from .bat files) it works, but if i start both node and hub from a .bat situated on my hub , it doesn't work ! really cannot explain

Comment: To be clear - are you trying to run hub and node from the same .bat file?

Comment: On HUB I start the server and ,at the same time, a .bat (situated on node) that will start the node     :          
HUB
start java -jar C:\workspace\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar  -role hub -port 4444
psexec.exe \\XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -s -e -u USER -p PASSWORD -i 2 C:\Selenium\StartNode.bat
NODE
java -jar C:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node  -hub http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:4444/grid/register

Comment: So if you use exactly the same script (`java -jar C:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -hub XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:4444/grid/register`) for running node locally on node machine that's works fine, yes? Maybe some additional rules were added to your LAN?